# How to improve performance of the following code in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

```
for i in range(N):
   for j in range(M):
      l2 = numpy.argmin(numpy.abs(s - dE[i,j]))
      A[l1,l2] = A[l1,l2] + (n[j]+1)*I[i,j]
```

Basically, what it does is to locate the value of `dE[i,j]` in an array of `s`, and add a corresponding value `(n[j]+1)*I[i,j]` to the location. Is there anyway to avoid the for loops?

Comment: I don't see how `l1` is set.  But I suspect if you could get `l2` for all `i,j`, the addition to `A[l1,l2]` could be done with one numpy expression.  If the `l1,l2` values have duplicates that addition will be more complicated, but not impossible.  So my guess is the `argmin` expression is the sticking point.  You might focus on eliminating the `j` loop first.

Answer (score 1):

You could technically use `for i, j in it.product(range(N), range(M)):   do_something()`, but honestly, the bottleneck is the `argmin` and the time complexity of the loop: you're in slow territory due to your algorithm's design. Think about finding ways to refactor, if possible, or write an extension in C if the performance is prohibitive and there is no way to refactor.

If the performance is not a bottleneck, YAGNI: You ain't gonna need it. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I was trying to look for a Python version of Value_Locate(s, dE) as implemented in IDL, where dE can be either a number or multidimensional array. But for some reason such function is missing in Python, or maybe it exists in another package than Numpy? It would be nice if Numpy could improve argmin by adding a feature to deal with array.

Comment: @Paitel, likely because it's very different depending on the array dimensions and where or not the matrix/array is sorted. If the data is sorted, you could use `searchsorted()` and dramatically cut your time complexity.